# Grid using hf-tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, hf-tikz

Related of this question,
[How can I put a grid/squared paper behind a single formula?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622542/how-can-i-put-a-grid-squared-paper-behind-a-single-formula)
I would to say if with `hf-tikz`, package of Claudio Fiandrino that I sent my best regards, exist a way to have a grid in a generic formula.
Here I put a MWE (it is not perfect because I have an error or missing `;`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
  \tikzmarkin[set fill color=green!50!lime!30,
              set border color=green!40!black]{a}(0.2,-0.4)(-0.2,0.6)
    x+1=566
  \tikzmarkend{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Options `set (fill|border) color` are only defined with package option `customcolors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

- add `hf-tikz` package option `customcolors`
- provide new option `grid pattern=<length>` which consists of `preaction` and pattern options used in [@mais' answer to the former question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622553).
- include tikz library `pattern.meta`

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
   grid pattern/.style={
    % copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622553
    preaction={fill, black!10!white},
    pattern={Hatch[distance=#1, xshift=0.5*#1, yshift=0.5*#1, line width=0.05*#1]},
    pattern color=black!20!white,
   }
}

\[
  \tikzmarkin[%set fill color=green!50!lime!30,
              set border color=green!40!black, % or "draw=green!40!black,"
              hf-tikz nodes=2mm]{a}(0.2,-0.4)(-0.2,0.6)
    x+1=566
  \tikzmarkend{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your editing on my question. Now I see that always it is necessary to use \usetikzlibrary (hence tikz-pgf) to set another new enviroment as your excellent answer. Thank you again because my brain in this period it is not very clean. In fact I have not read the documentation as to use {hf-tikz}: to see \usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}. + 1 and check mark.

Comment: Actually I learnt the package option from its source. I’ve also shown a tikz alternative (`draw=<color>`) to `set border color=<color>` so the use of package option `customcolors` could be optional.